# JMS Client Routing

Tags: java, jms

Hi guys i am developing a JMS client at work. I understand my JMS resourses that is ConnectionFactory,QueueConnectionFactory and Queue/Topic. I have develped this using java an it works well on my local server machine using glassfish.

I want to be sure whats my Connectionfactory or QueueConnectionFactory from this routing point i received. How will i implement connect to the vPN server. The CSD port is 7016 and CSD IP: 10.10.10.76

```
<routingPoint>
            <name>CSD</name>
            <inboundQueue>interfaceCsdOut</inboundQueue>
            <outboundQueue>interfaceCsdIn</outboundQueue>
               <context>glassfish-csd</context>
            <matchingKey>DESTINATION</matchingKey>
            <controlPoint>SWITCH</controlPoint>
        </routingPoint>
```

This is a snippet of the java code im using to connect on my local machine.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
                      props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "mq://127.0.0.1:7676");

                               // Create the initial context for remote JMS server
               InitialContext cntxt = new InitialContext(props);
                      //System.out.println("Context Created");  
  // JNDI Lookup for QueueConnectionFactory in remote JMS Provider
                      QueueConnectionFactory qFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory)cntxt.lookup("TestQueueConnectionFactory");

  // Create a Connection from QueueConnectionFactory
                       Connection connection = qFactory.createConnection();
                          //System.out.println("Connection established with JMS Provider ");

  // Initialise the communication session 
                  Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

  // Create the message
                     TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
                       message.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
                        message.setText(finalm);

                          // JNDI Lookup for the Queue in remote JMS Provider
                                 Queue queue = (Queue)cntxt.lookup("jms/Escrow");

                               // Create the MessageProducer for this communication 
                               // Session on the Queue we have
                             MessageProducer mp = session.createProducer(queue);

                                // Send the message to Queue
                                 mp.send(message);
                                 //System.out.println(finalm);

                                 // Make sure all the resources are released 
                                       mp.close();
                                 session.close();
                                cntxt.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to connect to these queues form an external client.

In that case this client needs to have some client jars such as JMS Client. Your Provider URL is:

> iiop://10.10.10.76:7016

(check the port to make sure it is the bootstrap port)

Connectionfactory or QueueConnectionFactory is

> TestQueueConnectionFactory

And your queue:

> jms/Escrow

Your client code could looks as follows if you were using websphere and have importent the jms client jars: (for Glassfish should be similar)

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.StringWriter; 
import java.util.Hashtable; 

import javax.jms.Connection; 
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory; 
import javax.jms.JMSException; 
import javax.jms.MessageProducer; 
import javax.jms.Queue; 
import javax.jms.Session; 
import javax.jms.TextMessage; 
import javax.naming.Context; 
import javax.naming.InitialContext; 
import javax.naming.NamingException; 
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder; 
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory; 
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException; 
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys; 
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer; 
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException; 
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory; 
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource; 
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult; 

import org.json.JSONException; 
import org.json.JSONObject; 
import org.w3c.dom.Attr; 
import org.w3c.dom.Document; 
import org.w3c.dom.Element; 

public class SimpleClientLast { 


        public static void main(String args[]) throws JMSException, NamingException { 

                Hashtable env = new Hashtable(); 
                env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
                                "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory"); 
                env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://10.10.10.76:7016"); 

                Context jndiContext = null; 
                try { 
                        jndiContext = new InitialContext(env); 
                } catch (NamingException e) { 

                        System.out.println("Could not create JNDI API context: " 
                                        + e.toString()); 
                        System.exit(1); 
                } 

                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext 
                                .lookup("TestQueueConnectionFactory"); 
                Connection qConn = connectionFactory.createConnection(); 
                Session qSession = qConn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); 
                Queue q = (Queue) jndiContext.lookup("jms/Escrow"); 

                System.out.println("before"); 
                MessageProducer producer = qSession.createProducer(q); 
                TextMessage message = qSession.createTextMessage(); 

                System.out.println("JSON begin: "); 
                String jsonText = "{"mytext":"myTextDetails"}" 

                System.out.println(jsonText); 
                message.setText(jsonText); 
                producer.send(message); 

                System.out.println("JSON end."); 

                System.out.println("after"); 

                producer.close(); 
                qSession.close(); 
                qConn.close(); 

        }
```

Comment: we are suppose to use                                                                                           <routingPoint>
            <name>CSD</name>
            <inboundQueue>interfaceCsdOut</inboundQueue>
            <outboundQueue>interfaceCsdIn</outboundQueue>
               <context>glassfish-csd</context>
            <matchingKey>DESTINATION</matchingKey>
            <controlPoint>SWITCH</controlPoint>
        </routingPoint>   My queue is interfaceCsdIn